# moving from localhost socket to TCP/IP increased execution time

Tags: mysql, tcp

recently we revoked grants of localhost on mysql .
I had mysql and scripts running on same server and we use to connect data mysql through socket (localhost) and it used to take 1 hr for a data intensive script to run.
But when we starting using TCP/IP to connect to mysql my script's execution time increased drastically. now it takes 3.5 hr to complete.

Can somebody suggest what  could be the possible reason?
I understand moving from local socket connection to TCP/IP would increase time but the leap would be this much I'm unable to figure out.

Please help me

Comment: Is the mysql server still running on same machine, but accessed using FQDN? Or has it been migrated to a remote server, and accessed over internet?

Comment: mysql is still on same server . its just we are accessing it from server's IP.